# How to add a back button to my Chewie video player in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to add a back button to my video player screen when it's launched. This is so, the user can easily go back when clicked on it. I can't seem to find an easy way to do this without messing with the default Chewie controls.

Here is my current ChewieController setup

```
void _initializeVideoPlayer() {
    final videoPlayerController = widget.galleryItems[0].url != null
        ? VideoPlayerController.network(widget.galleryItems[0].url!)
        : VideoPlayerController.file(widget.galleryItems[0].file!);
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
      allowFullScreen: true,
      autoInitialize: true,
      looping: false,
      showControlsOnInitialize: false,
      hideControlsTimer: const Duration(seconds: 4),
      autoPlay: true,
      allowMuting: true,
      allowPlaybackSpeedChanging: false,
      materialProgressColors: ChewieProgressColors(
        playedColor: AppColors.primaryColor,
        handleColor: AppColors.primaryColor,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        bufferedColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
      ),
      errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
        return Center(
          child: Text(errorMessage),
        );
      },
    );
```

The reason I want to add the back button to the existing chewie controls is because I want it to also be part of the default chewi hide and show controls animation when the video is playing. If not I could just achieve this with a Stack widget.